# Infinite Loop in War Card Game Simulator

Tags: python, oop

I'm trying to simulate a (tiny) game of War! as an exercise in OOP. I have a loop that plays two decks against each other, but it seems to loop forever, repeating the same sequence again and again. The output gets to the point where one deck has 4 card objects in it, and then the loop repeats. The loop should only be running when both Drawpile objects are greater than zero.

```
ranks = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14] #for use of value comparison via index
suits =['Diamonds','Hearts','Clubs','Spades']
rounds = 0

class Card:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit): 
        self.rank = rank
        assert rank in ranks
        assert suit in suits
        self.suit = suit
    def __repr_(self):
        return '{} of {}'.format(self.rank,self.suit)
    def __str__(self):
        return '{} of {}'.format(self.rank,self.suit)
    def __eq__(self, other): 
        if self.rank == other.rank:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def __gt__(self, other): #gt compared via ordering of ranks index
        if self.rank > other.rank:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.rank < other.rank:
            return True
        else:
            return False

class Drawpile:
    def __init__(self, pile =[]):
        self.pile = pile
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.pile)
    def __getitem__(self, n):
        return self.pile[n]
    def add(self, n):
        self.pile.append(n)
    def draw(self):
        if len(self) <= 0:
            return None
        return self.pile.pop(0)

dp1 = Drawpile([Card(2,'Diamonds'),Card(13,'Hearts'),Card(7,'Clubs')])
dp2 = Drawpile([Card(4,'Hearts'),Card(3,'Hearts'),Card(8,'Spades')])

while len(dp1) > 0 and len(dp2) > 0:

    rounds += 1
    c1 = dp1.draw()
    c2 = dp2.draw()

    print('Round ',rounds)
    print('c1',c1, len(dp1))
    print('c2',c2, len(dp2))

    if c1 > c2:
        dp1.add(c1)
        dp1.add(c2)
    else:
        dp2.add(c1)
        dp2.add(c2)

if len(dp1) > len(dp2):
    print('Pile 1 Won!')
else:
    print('Pile 2 Won!')
```

Can anyone tell me where exactly this loop is getting stuck? I've tried diagramming it out and this is my second rewrite. Any ideas?

Comment: DP2's last card is always 8 of spades, so it always wins another 2 cards

Comment: Do you need to shuffle?

Comment: I think it's not the algorithm, but just a coincidence of the order and selection of cards. Try playing the game manually with the chosen cards, and see if it ends, or continues ad infinitem (be aware of the order in which cards won are appended to the existing deck).

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a truly infinite loop: that's the nature of the game.  There is no guaranteed end.  Here's a segment of the trace you provide (good work!) that shows the looping.  The first and last rounds listed are identical; the decks behind these are also the same in both cases.  If you want a finite game, you'll need to implement some sort of resolution to this situation.

```
Round  64274
c1 13 of Hearts 3
c2 4 of Hearts 1
Round  64275
c1 2 of Diamonds 4
c2 8 of Spades 0
Round  64276
c1 7 of Clubs 3
c2 2 of Diamonds 1
Round  64277
c1 3 of Hearts 4
c2 8 of Spades 0
Round  64278
c1 13 of Hearts 3
c2 3 of Hearts 1
Round  64279
c1 4 of Hearts 4
c2 8 of Spades 0
Round  64280
c1 7 of Clubs 3
c2 4 of Hearts 1
Round  64281
c1 2 of Diamonds 4
c2 8 of Spades 0
Round  64282
c1 13 of Hearts 3
c2 2 of Diamonds 1
Round  64283
c1 3 of Hearts 4
c2 8 of Spades 0
Round  64284
c1 7 of Clubs 3
c2 3 of Hearts 1
Round  64285
c1 4 of Hearts 4
c2 8 of Spades 0
Round  64286
c1 13 of Hearts 3
c2 4 of Hearts 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I added a condition in the while loop to exit when either of the decks hits len(0). The logic for card swapping was all happening without hitting the check of the while loop from I gather. Code is now functional :)